# Make every n-th slice of a 3-d numpy array consecutive

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

### Statement

Let's say we have some 3-dimesional numpy array, `A`, which has shape `(X, Y, Z)`. I want to create a new array `B`, which will also have shape `(X, Y, Z)`.

We desire that the first n slices (`:n`) of `B` along the zero-th axis correspond to every m-th slice (`::m`) of `A` along the zero-th axis.

We also desire that slices `n:2*n` of `B` correspond to every `m+1`-th slice (`1::m` ) of `A`. And so on for the rest of the array.

What is the best way to achieve this using vectorized numpy computations?

### Example

The above statement is best understood by an example. So let's start by setting up some example array `A`:

```py
import numpy as np

# Create array A with shape (15, 3, 3)
n = 3; m = 5
a = np.array([i * np.eye(3) for i in range(1, 1+m)])
A = np.tile(a, (n, 1, 1))
```

If we take a look at some of the zero-th slices of `A` we have that:

```py
print(A[0])
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
print(A[1])
[[2. 0. 0.]
 [0. 2. 0.]
 [0. 0. 2.]]
```

...

```py
print(A[4])
[[5. 0. 0.]
 [0. 5. 0.]
 [0. 0. 5.]]
print(A[5])
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
```

and so on.

The values in `A` *are not important*, but should help illustrate the original statement.

I would like to know if we can create matrix `B` using numpy functions only. Array `B` should have slices:

```py
print(B[0])
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
print(B[1])
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
print(B[2])
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
print(B[3])
[[2. 0. 0.]
 [0. 2. 0.]
 [0. 0. 2.]]
```

and so on.

Is there any way to generate `B` from `A` with a pure numpy solution?

### What I've tried

The following gives `B` as desired, but it becomes tedious as `m` gets large:

```py
# vstack solution
B = np.vstack((A[::m], A[1::m], A[2::m], A[3::m], A[4::m]))
```

Using a list comprehension also works, but I'd like to avoid using loops:

```py
# List comprehension solution
B = np.vstack([A[i::m] for i in range(m)])
```

Comment: So in your example `n` is 3? But then where it says `print(B[4])` and `print(B[5])`, shouldn't it be `print(B[2])` and `print(B[3])`?

Comment: Sorry, clumsy editing. You're right. I'll alter the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
import numpy as np

# Create array A with shape (15, 3, 3)
a = np.array([i * np.eye(3) for i in range(1, 6)])
A = np.tile(a, (3, 1, 1))

B = np.swapaxes(A.reshape(3, 5, 3, 3), 0, 1)
B = B.reshape(-1, 3, 3)
print(B)
# [[[1. 0. 0.]
#   [0. 1. 0.]
#   [0. 0. 1.]]
#
#  [[1. 0. 0.]
#   [0. 1. 0.]
#   [0. 0. 1.]]
#
#  [[1. 0. 0.]
#   [0. 1. 0.]
#   [0. 0. 1.]]
#
#  [[2. 0. 0.]
#   [0. 2. 0.]
#   [0. 0. 2.]]
# ...
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you, this is a great solution. Reshaping to 4d and swapping the axes is very clever!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, maybe you can just use [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
B = np.sort(A, axis = 0)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this solution. You're right that it manipulates```A``` into ```B``` for the example. However, the numbers in the array aren't important and this doesn't solve the more general statement given at the top of my question. I think this is my fault as the example could be misleading. @jdehesa has a good solution below.

Answer (score 1):

***Setup***

```
n = 3; m = 5
a = np.array([i * np.eye(n) for i in range(1, 1+m)])
```

---

Instead of `tile`, use `np.repeat` along axis 0, and reshape using Fortran-style ordering.

```
np.repeat(a, n, 0).reshape(m*n, n, n, order='F')
```

```
array([[[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]],

       [[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]],

       [[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]],

       [[2., 0., 0.],
        [0., 2., 0.],
        [0., 0., 2.]],    
       ...    
       [[5., 0., 0.],
        [0., 5., 0.],
        [0., 0., 5.]]])
```

***Validation***

```
# your approach
A = np.tile(a, (n, 1, 1))
B = np.vstack((A[::m], A[1::m], A[2::m], A[3::m], A[4::m]))

# my approach
usr_B = np.repeat(a, n, 0).reshape(m*n, n, n, order='F')

>>> np.array_equal(B, usr_B)
True
```

***Timings***

```
%%timeit
A = np.tile(a, (n, 1, 1))
B = np.vstack((A[::m], A[1::m], A[2::m], A[3::m], A[4::m]))
19 µs ± 57.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%%timeit
A = np.tile(a, (3, 1, 1))
B = np.swapaxes(A.reshape(3, 5, 3, 3), 0, 1)
B = B.reshape(-1, 3, 3)
11 µs ± 74.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.repeat(a, n, 0).reshape(m*n, n, n, order='F')
2.68 µs ± 21.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Maybe you could clarify a few points for me I think I don't understand. In your solution I don't see the array ```A``` created at any point --- which is the starting point of this question. I'm not really clear on the purpose of the ```.reshape(m*n, n, n, order='F')``` command either: it doesn't seem to alter ```np.repeat(a, n, 0)```.

Comment: @jwalton3141 You don't *need* to create `A`, using this solution, I only use the original array `a` to get your desired output.  The reshaping works just fine, you just need to reassign the result to another variable in order to see the output, it won't modify the array in place.

Comment: I understand. I think my question may have misled you as ```A``` **is** the starting point of this question. I wanted to know how to get from ```A``` to ```B```, not from ```a``` to ```B```. I did try to make this clear in my question though